# Does the parameter get passed to the bracket inside the lambda expression or to the method inside the interface?

Tags: java

I am confused whether the 10,20,30 inside db.dydx(10,20,30) get passed to the dydx method inside the DragonBall interface or the bracket inside the lambda expression (double w, double q, double e)

```
interface DragonBall
{
    double dydx(double q, double w, double e);
}

class A
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    
      
      DragonBall db = (double q, double w, double e) -> q * 10; 
      System.out.println(db.dydx(10,20,30));    
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiEZ5.png)

Comment: You can't pass anything "to the interface" because it has no executable code. The only thing that implements the `dydx` method of that interface in your code is the lambda, so the parameters get passed to the lambda body.

Comment: This link here gives you a more in depth explanation, from it just drop the annotation `@FunctionalInterface` which is not needed. https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2191423&seqNum=2#:~:text=A%20lambda%20expression%20(lambda)%20is,are%20known%20as%20functional%20interfaces.&text=A%20functional%20interface%20can%20define,static%20methods%20as%20it%20requires.

Answer (score 1):

`DragonBall db = (double q, double w, double e) -> q * 10;`

is a shortcut for

```
DragonBall db = new DragonBall() {
    double dydx(double q, double w, double e) {
       return q * 10;
    }
}
```

You implemented the interface and that's where your data is processed.

Comment: Is it the same thing?

class DragonBall 
{
 public double dydx(double q, double w, double e)
    {
   return q * 10;
    }
}

class hello
{
 public static void main(String args)
 {
  DragonBall db = new DragonBall(); 
  
  System.out.println(db.dydx(10,20,30));
 }
}